# Use find() to determine a conditional's outcome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble understanding how I can use `find()` within a conditional?

Basically if the `item.label` is equal to the `e.target.value` I want the conditional statement to equal true.

```
if (this.props.Items.find(item => item.label === e.target.value)) {
    // Both values match
}
```

Any idea where I might be going wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `some` method by passing a provided *callback* function as argument.

```
if (this.props.Items.some(item => item.label === e.target.value)) {
    // Both values match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `some` here as it tells whether is there any item matching the criteria or not.

```
if (this.props.Items.some(item => item.label === e.target.value)) {
    // Both values match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, your code works. But in case you really want the return value of array.find to be true or false, you can cast it by using `!!`:

```
if (!!this.props.Items.find(item => item.label === e.target.value)) {
    // Both values match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Javascript some() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). I think that's what you're after.